# Referenced Project in Blazor WebAssembly does nothing during runtime

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I Have a Project with 2 Solutions that both need to use a common backend.
One runs on .Net 4.8 Mvc, which has the Backend (Console application) referenced as a Project. This runs fine.

The new project is a Blazor Webassembly. I can reference the backend without a problem and during building I receive no errors. When I run the Blazor Project, the referenced backend doesn't seem to do anything. I get no error, no stacktrace. It just ignores it. I created a testclass in the backend, and upon running in debugmode and initializing the class, the class isn't null but upon inspection says "children could not be evaluated."

Does anynone know what i can do? I tried playing with the project reference properties but nothing seems to solve my problem. Im Using Visual studio 2022.

Comment: Can you provide more context to how the Blazor WASM app is calling/referencing the backend?  Also-- if you recreated the project using the Blazor Server template, do you still have the same problem?  MVC runs server-side, WASM runs client/browser-side, might be your problem. Typically for Blazor WASM, you need to pair it with a backend API project that you can make HTTP calls.